# Multiple ng class with true/false issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the ng-class directive like this:

```
ng-class = "{
    'checked' : modal.isUserChecked(user.id),
    'disabled': modal.isDisabledUser(user.id),
    'checked': user.status === 'invited',
    'participator': user.status === 'participator'
}"
```

and expression does not work properly (`'checked'` and `'disabled'` is not adding).

The expression works properly when rewrite code to array of objects,

```
[{
    'checked': modal.isUserChecked(user.id)
} {
    'disabled': modal.isDisabledUser(user.id)
}]
```

but it looks like be no necessary (in the lot of situations simple object with parameters is enough)

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
ng-class = "{
  'checked' : modal.isUserChecked(user.id) && user.status === 'invited', 
  'disabled' : modal.isDisabledUser(user.id),
  'participator' : user.status === 'participator'
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 2 different conditions for same class, if you have to do it, combine the conditions in one:-

Example

```
ng-class = "{
  'checked' : modal.isUserChecked(user.id) && user.status === 'invited', 
  'disabled' : modal.isDisabledUser(user.id),
  'participator' : user.status === 'participator'
}"
```

OR

```
ng-class = "{
  'checked' : modal.isUserChecked(user.id) || user.status === 'invited', 
  'disabled' : modal.isDisabledUser(user.id),
  'participator' : user.status === 'participator'
}"
```

For more check this out article to see all use cases of ng-class

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass